# A C++ linking error

Tags: c++, linker

I have a linking error which I think I should not have:

```
koala.o:
  In function `ns1::utils::io::protocol::InputSequenceFile
    <
      ns1::utils::io::protocol::TargetSequenceProtocol<
        ns1::utils::io::FooIndexTarget
      >
      , false
    >::InputSequenceFile(ns1::utils::io::DataFileDescriptor const&) [clone .constprop.1291]':
koala.cpp:(.text+0x332a):
  undefined reference to 
    `ns1::utils::io::DataFileFactory::createIndexedInputFile
    (
      ns1::utils::io::DataFileDescriptor const&, ns1::utils::io::IndexMode::Enum, bool
    )'
```

(I changed only whitespaces so it can be read more easily. I also did some anonimization with great care.)

Then I used `nm` to discover the case about the symbols:

```
nm other.o:
0000000000008f20 t _ZN4ns15utils2io15DataFileFactory22createIndexedInputFileERKNS1_18DataFileDescriptorENS1_9IndexMode4EnumEb.constprop.1677

nm koala.o:
                 U _ZN4ns15utils2io15DataFileFactory22createIndexedInputFileERKNS1_18DataFileDescriptorENS1_9IndexMode4EnumEb
```

(grepped outputs)

They are the same not counting the `constprop.1677` (which I don't know what it is). The method in question is a static method of a class. I need some help to understand the root cause of the problem.

Comment: You forgot to link with a library/object file?

Comment: I don't think. `man nm`: "t": The symbol is in the text (code) section. `man nm`: "U" The symbol is undefined. So I have a `t` for the thing that is required by the `U` except the `constprop.1677` part which is not something I would ever write anywhere.

Comment: What's your command line?

Comment: I don't know what `constprop`is either, but perhaps there's a `const` and non-`const` overload of that function, but only one of them is implemented?

Comment: @Angew constprop means gcc (or clang, the OP is still obscure on this topic) duplicated the function because it saw a chance to optimise it with respect to constant propagation. We'll need to see how exactly he compiles and links his objects. See the -fipa-cp-clone switch for gcc.

Comment: how are you compiling the .cpp files? Maybe you miss the one where the method is implemented (defined)

Comment: I compile it with gcc with a very log command line which would be very hard to anonimize. But I will try it.

Comment: @mockinterface: That is it. `man g++` with the `-fipa-cp-clone` info does give answer to my question. At least I understand the problem, so I can move on with it. Please convert your suggestion into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I had `-O3` which includes `-fipa-cp-clone`, so I added `-fno-ipa-cp-clone` and the problem disappeared. That is a bad trade so I need to find a more delicate solution for the problem later. Describing my whole build process or even giving the command line would be an enormous work (because the need for anonimization), so I rather skip it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-O3` switch for gcc turns `-fipa-cp-clone` on by default, add `-fno-ipa-cp-clone` to the command line to disable.

The switch enables the relevant optimisation in control and reach flow analysis in the compiler that introduces collapsed cloned versions of the functions that can be shown to be of a constant value, and in the compiled objects those clones can be identified by the `.constprop` suffix.

---

**Background**

> Constant propagation is a well-known global flow analysis problem. The
>   goal of constant propagation is to discover values that are constant
>   on all possible executions of a program and to propagate these
>   constant values as far forward through the program as possible.
>   Expressions whose operands are all constants can be evaluated at
>   compile time and the results propagated further.
>
> Wegman, Mark N; Zadeck, F. Kenneth (April 1991), "Constant Propagation with Conditional Branches", ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems 13 (2): 181–210

Here's a concrete example:

```
int foo (int x, int y) {
   if (y == 0) return 0;
   return foo (x, --y) % 2;
}

int main () {
   int z = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {       
       z = z + foo (1, i);
   }
}

// g++-4.8 -c -O2 -fipa-cp-clone main.cpp && nm main.o
0000000000000030 T _Z3fooii
0000000000000000 t _Z3fooii.constprop.0
0000000000000000 T main
```

You can observe that with `-fipa-cp-clone` the compiler identifies that there is a constant being passed to an externally visible `foo()` method and prepares for the optimisation by cloning the function.

([**See live here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c14ef6cbcc14dbd))

Comment: So "-fno-ipa-cp-clone" to the build command-line will fix the problem, but why does it occur in the first place? How come GCC can't link its own output in this case?